# How to copy a multi cell array function from horizontally to vertically

Tags: excel

I founded a sheet with an array function :

https://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/using-linest-on-data-with-gaps/#comment-11068

The array function is entered in cells D20:G20 from sheet "Data with gaps".
I would like to have the cells vertically in cells L20:L22.
For some reason i do not succeed. I do succeed to copy the cells, but only horizontally. I also tried Transpose-copy and the Transpose-function although i do not succeed.

I hope someone knows a solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

My question was answered on the [original forum](https://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/using-linest-on-data-with-gaps/#comment-11070):

> You can wrap the function with the Transpose function:
>
> **`=TRANSPOSE(LINESTgap(C4:C14,A4:A14^{1,2}))`**
>
> Enter the function as above, then select three rows in a single column
>   (with the function In the top row), and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>